# ESP WifiClient(TSP/IP) получает не все ответы от С# SocketServer

Tags: c#, сокет, esp8266

есть код C# для создания Socket:

```
            public static void Creat_S()
            {
                // получаем адреса для запуска сокета
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
                IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
                             // создаем сокет
                Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    // связываем сокет с локальной точкой, по которой будем принимать данные
                    listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);

                    // начинаем прослушивание
                    listenSocket.Listen(10);

                    Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                        // получаем сообщение
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                        byte[] data = new byte[256]; // буфер для получаемых данных

                        do
                        {
                            bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                            builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                        }
                        while (handler.Available > 0);

                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());

                        // отправляем ответ
                        string message = "ваше сообщение доставлено";
                        data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                        handler.Send(data);
                        // закрываем сокет
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

есть код на ESP8266, там создается клиент, отправляет сообщения и получает ответ:

```
void server_(String mess)
   {    
      if (client.connect(server, server_port)) 
      {
        Serial.println("Server_connect");
        client.println(mess);
        client.println();
      }
      else{Serial.println("Couldn't get a server connection");}

      while (client.connected())
      {
        if (client.available())
        {
          char c = client.read();
          Serial.print(c);
        }
      }
     client.stop();
     Serial.println("\n[Disconnected]");
    }
```

все соединяется, все сообщения от Client доходят до Server. Но ответ от Server приходят не все, в мониторе порта ESP есть отображение только части ответов. Не понимаю кто лагает Client/Server? Как добиться получения всех ответов от Server?

Comment: Если вы используете TCP/IP, то вам удобнее будет реализовать это не на сокетах, а на `TcpClient`/`TcpListener`, нет смысла пренебрегать уже готовым велосипедом. А пока вы проводите слишком низкоуровневую работу, где очень легко ошибиться. Например вы по непонятным причинам не используете [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async), без которого здесь ну вообще никак.

Answer (score 0):

Всё было банально....ESP на Mega похоже лагает. Подключил другую ESP8266MOD, загрузил скетч..Ответы от Сервера приходят !!!абсолютно!!! на все отправки. Проблема оказалась в железе.